# Get all retweets with tweet id list

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I am trying to get all retweets from tweet_ids list. I have a tweetlist.csv file. I got tweet.id column from this file. I added all tweet id into tweet_ids list. Then I want to get all retweet which belong to these tweet ids.  I did it with tweepy. i am getting TooManyRequests error. How can I do without getting this error?

My code is below.

`

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=('id_str','in_reply_to_status_id','in_reply_to_user_id',
                           'in_reply_to_screen_name','user','is_quote_status',
                           'tweet_text', 'tweet_sentiment',
                           'user_followers_count', 'user_friends_count',
                           'user_account_age', 'user_verified',
                           'user_favourites_count', 'user_tweets',
                           'tweet_retweeted', 'tweet_retweet_count', 'tweet_favorite_count'))
    
df1.sort_values("tweet_text", inplace = True) 
df1.drop_duplicates(subset ="tweet_text", keep = False, inplace = True) 

for tweet_id in tweet_ids:
    
    retweet_list = api.get_retweets(tweet_id,count=10)

    length = len(retweet_list)
    if(length > 0 ):
        for tweet in retweet_list:
            sentimentText = TextBlob(tweet.text)
            df1 = df1.append({'id_str': tweet.id_str,
                    'in_reply_to_status_id': tweet.in_reply_to_status_id,
                    'in_reply_to_user_id': tweet.in_reply_to_status_id,
                    'in_reply_to_screen_name': tweet.in_reply_to_screen_name,
                    'user': tweet.user.id,
                    'is_quote_status': tweet.is_quote_status,
                    'tweet_text': re.sub(r'http\S+', '', tweet.text), # Removing any URL's in the tweet text here
                    'tweet_sentiment': sentimentText.sentiment.polarity,
                    'user_followers_count': tweet.user.followers_count, 
                    'user_friends_count': tweet.user.friends_count,
                    'user_account_age': tweet.user.created_at, 
                    'user_verified': tweet.user.verified,
                    'user_favourites_count': tweet.user.favourites_count,
                    'user_tweets': tweet.user.statuses_count,
                    'tweet_retweeted': tweet.retweeted,
                    'tweet_retweet_count': tweet.retweet_count,
                    'tweet_favorite_count': tweet.favorite_count},
                   ignore_index=True)
df1.head()
```

`

I got following error

> 

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TooManyRequests                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-2ae54f6fa723> in <module>
     17 for tweet_id in tweet_ids:
     18 
---> 19     retweet_list = api.get_retweets(tweet_id,count=10)
     20 
     21     length = len(retweet_list)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     44             kwargs['payload_list'] = payload_list
     45             kwargs['payload_type'] = payload_type
---> 46             return method(*args, **kwargs)
     47         wrapper.payload_list = payload_list
     48         wrapper.payload_type = payload_type

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py in get_retweets(self, id, **kwargs)
    816             'GET', f'statuses/retweets/{id}', endpoint_parameters=(
    817                 'count', 'trim_user'
--> 818             ), **kwargs
    819         )
    820 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py in request(self, method, endpoint, endpoint_parameters, params, headers, json_payload, parser, payload_list, payload_type, post_data, files, require_auth, return_cursors, upload_api, use_cache, **kwargs)
    261                 raise NotFound(resp)
    262             if resp.status_code == 429:
--> 263                 raise TooManyRequests(resp)
    264             if resp.status_code >= 500:
    265                 raise TwitterServerError(resp)

TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests
88 - Rate limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with "wait_on_rate_limit=True"

in the tweepy call, I added this value. It works

```
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```